# Is it possible (theoretically) to divide Black Hole into two parts?

Tags: black-holes, black-hole-thermodynamics

I have read that it's not possible.

Comment: Why minus? I faced with problem in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960194909814 : <<even as a thought experiment a black hole itself cannot be divided into two or more subsystems>>...

Comment: Define what you mean by "dividing" a black hole and what do you mean by "parts". Do you want to separate the matter composing the black whole in two? At what distance?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45448/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, assuming that all tools we could use are "normal" in some particular sense (that is, they agree with some [energy conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition)). That means, they are made of particles and fields that cannot travel faster that light, for one example. Everything physicists discovered so far is "normal" in that sense, and it is highly unbelievable that we would come across something not "normal" in the future.

But if, theoretically, we are allowed to violate those conditions, then the answer is "we don't know". GR solutions are not explored enough in that area. I mention that to say that there is one possible loophole, though unlikely.